# PostgreSQL multiplies columns when joining two tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables similar to this example (simplified for clarity):

***parent:***

```
| id   |  name     | amount    | year  |
----------------------------------------
| 101  |  Henry    | 300       | 2020  |
----------------------------------------
| 102  |  Carol    | 100       | 2020  |
----------------------------------------
| 103  |  Tom      | 900       | 2020  |
----------------------------------------
```

***child:***

```
| id   |  parent_id  | department    |
--------------------------------------
| 1    |  101        | finance       |
--------------------------------------
| 2    |  101        | hr            |
--------------------------------------
| 3    |  101        | it            |
--------------------------------------
| 4    |  102        | support       |
--------------------------------------
```

I am trying to join two tables and get sum value of the amount field by the following script, but the sum would be 1900 instead of 1300 as the record 101 is repeated 3 times:

```
select 
sum(p.amount),
count(c) 
from parent p
left join child c on c.parent_id = p.id 
where p.year = 2020
```

When I use the following query, it works, but it gives count of child as 2 instead of 4 as it grouped the child records based on their parent:

```
SELECT 
SUM(p.amount),
COUNT(c) 
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id 
    FROM child
    GROUP BY parent_id
) c ON c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE p.year = 2020;
```

So, how to fix this problem?

Comment: it looks like you don't use any column of `child`, so why are you joining it? What are you exactly trying to calculate?

Comment: Actually, I need the count of corresponding child records,  but when I replace the `LEFT JOIN` part with the following, I get the correct sum, but the child count would be 2 instead of 4. `LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent_id FROM child GROUP BY parent_id) c ON c.parent_id = p.id`

Comment: @FlorianKlein Do you have an idea according to the last comment above?

Comment: do you mean you need the number of children each parent has?

Comment: anyway, wanted to avoid this before understanding the real need, but did you try `select sum(distinct p.amount)` ?

Comment: @FlorianKlein I tried it before asking the question, but if there are multiple amount with the same value for different parent record, then it gives wrong result as it eliminates one of these same values.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent_id, count(*) as childs FROM child GROUP BY parent_id) c ON c.parent_id = p.id`

Comment: @Arvo It gives wrong result for both count and sum of amount.

Comment: With your score you should know that it is essential to post the expected results. Your second query hat no `count` so how can you claim it returns `2 instead of 4`?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I simplify real query while posting related code in the question. I added missing line, now if the real problem is missing count, now you can share your suggestion with your score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following approach and fixed the problem by providing correct sum of the amounts in the parent table and count for the child one:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM parent WHERE year = 2020),
    COUNT(c) 
FROM child c;
```

Note: As the query will be transformed to HQL, I could not use `JOIN` with clause as in @SenthilPNathan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This query joins the tables, calculates the count of child records for each parent, and then sums up the parent amount and child count.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.amount) AS total_amount,
    sum(child_count) AS child_count
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS child_count
    FROM child
    GROUP BY parent_id
) c ON c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE p.year = 2020
```

While your query uses a subquery in the SELECT clause, which might be less efficient. Additionally, it doesn't explicitly join the tables, which might lead to confusion about how the child count is related to the parent records.

Comment: Voted up, but when I adapt it to `HQL`, it does not work as `JOIN` with clause is not supported in `HQL`.

Comment: @MuratYıldız, I focused on Postgres per your mention. This query doesn't use a join but relies on a WHERE clause with ID mapping. However, note that it might be slower due to the use of a subquery.

`SELECT 
    SUM(p.amount) AS total_amount,
    COALESCE(SUM(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child c WHERE c.parent_id = p.id)
    ), 0) AS child_count
FROM parent p
WHERE p.year = 2020`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to *calculate a total amount and the total number of childs* you must
first calculate the child count and join in the second step.

This query calculates the child count and returns the detailed data

```
with child_count as (
select parent_id, count(*) child_count 
from child
group by 1)
select 
  p.id, p.amount, c.child_count
from parent p
left outer join child_count c
on p.id = c.parent_id

id |amount|child_count|
---+------+-----------+
101|   300|          3|
102|   100|          1|
103|   900|           |
```

Adding the aggregation provides the requested result

```
with child_count as (
select parent_id, count(*) child_count 
from child
group by 1),
detail as (
select 
  p.id, p.amount, c.child_count
from parent p
left outer join child_count c
on p.id = c.parent_id)
select sum(amount) amount, sum(child_count) child_count
from detail

amount|child_count|
------+-----------+
  1300|          4|
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I created a new question by giving more details, could you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769607/extracting-multiple-result-with-child-tables-in-postgresql-and-hql/77769806#77769806) please?